# Template is missing. Missing template static_pages/home, application/home

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am following the Rails Tutorial by Michael Hartl and I keep getting this error when I visit the home page:

```
Template is missing
Missing template static_pages/home, application/home with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :jbuilder, :coffee]}
```

I know that quite a few people have asked about this error but nothing seems to be working for me. I have the home page file at app/views/layout/static_pages/home.html.erb.

Some of the answers to "Template is missing" made references to the **users_controller.rb** file. This is what I have:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
     end

  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)  
    if @user.save
       flash[:success] = "Welcome to the Sample App!"
       redirect_to @user
    else
       render 'new'
   end   
  end 

  private 
     def user_params
       params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email, :password,
                                      :password_confirmation)

   end 
  end
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: `mv app/views/layout/static_pages/home.html.erb app/views/static_pages/home.html.erb`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you tried to move the page (app/views/layout/static_pages/home.html.erb) one folder up? It seems Rails is looking for it outside the layout folder.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem,

It turns out it was a capitalisation on one of the files in my project the news page. I had it named as **News.html.erb** however in my routes file it was listed as pages#news so it was trying to route to a page that wasn't there.

try looking for any capitalisations and making sure that the files in the directories match up to the names in the routes file in terms of spelling and case sensitivity

A simple change to news.html.erb made sure that this worked.